# Shortcut for conditional assignment of managed object variable in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, dictionary

I am trying to update a core data object from a dictionary. The dictionary might not contain the value, so I need to assign the value in the dictionary on the condition it exists. The code below works but seems too long. Is there a way to make the conditional assignment more compact?

```
@NSManaged var title: String
...
func updateFromDict(dict :[String :String]){
    if dict["title"] != nil {
         self.title = dict["title"]!
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to update all keys in the dictionary you can use setValuesForKeysWithDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for `nil`, the *Swift-y* way is to use *optional binding*:

```
if let title = dict["title"] {
     self.title = title
}
```

This isn't really any shorter.

You can't make the assignment optional, but you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the value and just assign `self.title` to itself if `dict["title"]` is `nil`:

```
self.title = dict["title"] ?? self.title
```

---

If you want to get fancy, you could define your own operator `=?` that does the assignment if the right hand side is not `nil`:

```
infix operator =? {}

func =?<T> (inout lhs: T, rhs: T?) {
    if let value = rhs {
        lhs = value
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
self.title =? dict["title"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a one-liner using the built-in `map()` function
for Optionals:

```
// Swift 1.2:
map(dict["title"]) { self.title = $0 }

// Swift 2.0:
dict["title"].map { self.title = $0 }
```

The closure is only executed if `dict["title"]` is not `nil`, and then
`$0` is the unwrapped value.